# The category of theorems and proofs

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, proof-theory

On a philosophy website, it said that you could have a category with theorems as objects and proofs as arrows. This sounds awesome, but I couldn't find anything on the web that has both "category" and "proofs" in the title. Where it's some literature as a PDF of this category.

Comment: is your question how to define this category or are you looking for a mathematical study of this category?

Comment: @Ittay Weiss Both.

Answer (score 9):

This paper, called [Physics, Topology, Logic and Computation: A Rosetta Stone](http://arxiv.org/abs/0903.0340) does just that in section 3.2. If you have time and interest, I would suggest reading the entire paper (since the whole thing is pretty cool).

Answer (score 5):

The right way to build such a category is a philosophical question. There are different approaches in the mathematical literature. One thing is clear though: the objects should be propositions, not just theorems.

The problem is to define equality of proofs in a sensible way. For example, let $\Pi$ be Pythagoras' theorem. Should each of the over 100 proofs of $\Pi$ found [here](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/pythagoras/) be a different morphism $\top\to\Pi$? In that case, it is hard to see how composition of proofs can be defined in such a way that there is a unique "identity proof" for each proposition.

One approach is to consider some proofs *essentially equal* if some superficial transformations turn one proof into the other. This, however, shifts the problem of defining the equality of proofs to the problem of defining the equality of transformations of proofs. So proofs and propositions are actually part of some $\infty$-category. If you like this line of reasoning, take a look at [homotopy type theory](http://homotopytypetheory.org/) and its implementation in various [proof assistents](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_assistant).

Another approach is to simply consider every proof equal to any other proof of the same proposition, so that the category of propositions and proofs is a poset. For classical first order logic this poset is known as the [Lindenbaum-Taski algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindenbaum%E2%80%93Tarski_algebra).

The [$\lambda$-calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus) is a middle way between the infinity categories and the posets. Proofs can be encoded as $\lambda$-terms. A lot of irrelevant differences between proofs are lost in this encoding. There are equivalence relations on $\lambda$-term based on transformations like $\beta$-reduction. The counterpart of $\lambda$-calculi are [Cartesian closed categories](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_closed_category).

Comment: Incidentally, in your answer, you turned to topics very related to [a question I just asked](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/905822/what-is-the-desirable-function-identification-when-setting-up-arrows-in-the-cate).

Comment: @NicolajK: I can't help you there. Haskell needs "undefined" for Turing completeness. I don't know how changing the equivalence relation can repair the damage "undefined" does.

Comment: Why would Turing completeness suffer from taking aways "undefined"? I thought it's just convenient in case of non-termination or so. And how did you manage to write my user name with c?

Comment: In typed $\lambda$-calculi the terms that have types (other than "the type of everything" if that is present) have normal forms and therefore correspond to terminating computations. In other words, not all computer programs correspond to typed terms. Misspelling your username is really easy. With a little practice, you can do it too.

Comment: In my opinion this book seems quite wonderful  that I could find, but there will be many similar, think http://www.amazon.com/First-Order-Categorical-Logic-Model-Theoretical/dp/3540084398/ref=pd_sim_sbs_14_2?ie=UTF8&refRID=03Z6XJNNW249G0P0JX0Q

Comment: @WouterStekelenburg It would be more correct to say that haskell used `undefined` to model nontermination. If you didn't have `undefined`, you could easily make your own.

Comment: @PyRulez: more correct than what? If your explanation answers NikolajK's question, then please answer his question.

Comment: @WouterStekelenburg More correct than saying Haskell needs "undefined" for Turing completeness.

Comment: @PyRulez: I don't see that my explanation is any less correct since nontermination and Turing completeness are linked. Moreover, the way you state it wouldn't have helped NikolajK.

Answer (score 4):

See for example [*Lambek and Scott: Introduction to higher order categorical logic*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521356539), ch 0.1 (unfortunately not in the net but for sure in ur university library). There first is defined a **graph**, then a **deductive system** as a graph with

- For each object $A$ an **identity** arrow $1_A:A\rightarrow A$
- For each pair of arrows $f:A\rightarrow B$ and $g:B\rightarrow C$ the
  **composition** $gf:A\rightarrow C$

The idea of a logician might be that of objects as **formulas** and arrows as **deductions**, the composition in this context becoming a **rule of inference**
$$\frac{f:A\rightarrow B\space\space\space g:B\rightarrow C}{gf:A\rightarrow C}$$

However this is just an interpretation and letting this aside one can take that abstract definition of a deductive system to come out with the usual category:

A **category** is a deductive system with the ususal equations for **identity** and **associativity** - i.e. for $f:A\rightarrow B$, $g:B\rightarrow C$ and $h:C\rightarrow D$
$$f1_a=f=1_Bf,\space\space (hg)f=h(gf)$$

Comment: [Here it is](http://www.4shared.com/office/esFMX25Hba/Introduction_to_Higher-Order_C.html).

Comment: @user5402 broken